# Do injective outer measure-preserving functions preserve measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is an injection, such that for any $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $m^*(E)=m^*(f(E))$. Is it true that for any $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ measurable, $f(E)$ is always measurable?

Comment: why do you say "always"?